# When do MYSQL updates become visible?

Tags: mysql

If I run an INSERT or UPDATE from one process, and then at a later time (after I get a return value from the INSERT/UPDATE), from another process/computer run a SELECT, is it guaranteed that the results of the UPDATE will be visible by the SELECT?

I'm hoping/assuming the answer is "yes" but I couldn't find documentation, maybe because it's obvious.

I'm concerned that maybe there might be some kind of caching, or that there is something akin to a memory barrier, or that some kind of flush command needs to be called to ensure that the UPDATE/INSERT is visible to other connections.

If it matters, I am dealing with MyISAM tables.

Comment: I've never had problems with retrieving old data. So my guess is there is no caching or something it always updates or insert directly and when you make a select the updated or inserted data should be visible if it matches the criteria ofcourse.

Comment: Have you made sure that your updates got commited, such that the transaction is finished? That's the only setting that comes to my mind regarding your setup

Comment: MySQL does indeed have a [Query Cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html), which is believe was deprecated since MySQL 5.7 and removed in MySQL 8.. Also the Query Cache works like if a cached result had information from a table and that table was changed and the changed information would match the cached result filter the cache for that qeury would be invalided and the next query run would fetch the information from the table.

Comment: @NicoHaase MyISAM engine is in question, there are no transactions you can control, it runs in auto-commit mode. If MySQL returns true for an UPDATE or INSERT, then the data is immediately visible to subsequent queries, regardless of process that's asking for the data. TL;DR: **answer is yes**, you'll always get currently valid data.

Comment: @Mjh thanks for the answer.  That's what I thought.

Comment: @Refilon: I haven't had problems either, I just wanted to be sure that I "officially" could count on not having problems.  For example, in a multi-threaded context, if you ignore memory barriers and caching issues, you might go a long time without actually running into problems.  Just wanted to make sure there was no similar issue with MyISAM tables.